# 3-D Lebesgue measure of Menger sponge

Tags: lebesgue-measure, fractals

How can I prove that the $3-$dimensional Lebesgue measure of Menger sponge(which I know is a compact non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$) is equal to zero?

Comment: Well, how many cubes of side length $3^n$ do you need to cover the Menger sponge?

Comment: Alternatively, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, how many cubes of side length $3^{-n}$ do you *remove* from the unit cube in order to obtain the Menger sponge?

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks.